# App size getting bigger in ios + capacitor app update

Tags: javascript, ios, ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

I am using self hosted capago capacitor app update library for updating the app. It is working fine in android and ios. But in ios when multiple updates are done then the app size is getting bigger. I am deleting the previous bundles also. But still the size of the app is increasing. please advice